# How to convert Qt to C++?

Tags: c++, qt

I have an assignment where I have to convert a program that is written with the Qt library to standard C++ libraries. Shouldn't be too hard, right?

Is there a place online that shows the 'translation' of common qt library terms? Or could someone tell me how to change em? I need to change like 5 things:

- QList
- QStringList
- QFile
- QIODevice
- QTextStream
- toInt( )
- split( )

Comment: Qt is a c++ framework. Do you need to convert those to C++ STL objects?

Comment: Qt uses C++, do you mean without using Qt and using STL or what?

Comment: C++ is a programming language, Qt is a library written in C++. The classes you've listed have standard C++ library counterparts, so yeah, shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Pick each of those one at a time, see what features you need, and get started with a conversion. If you're stuck on a _specific_ problem, ask about it here with what you have so far and explaining specifically what you're not getting.

Comment: @khajvah & drahnr I dont need to conver them to STL objects, I just need to implement their C++ native library counterparts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to help you to get started:

QList is [std::list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list)

QStringList is basically QList < QString > , so it is the same

[std::fstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/) can be used for QFile

QIODevice  is maybe std::fstream, but I am not sure

Again std::fstream can be used for QTextStream

Comment: Note that in most cases there's no 1-to-1 replacement. For example `QList` acts more like a `std::vector` when the item type is a raw pointer and it is never a linked list (as `std::list`). (didnt downvote)

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Yeah, I know. It was just a fast search. When I say smth like "QList is std::list", I mean "std::list" can replace QList but whatever, I don't care. The point of my answer is to help the OP and I think, I did help...

Comment: for what I am doing vector does work better than list.